# how to align first li left and second li center in the ul element

Tags: html, css, alignment

Html:

```
<ul id="wr">
    <li id="l1"></li> // align left
    <li id="l2"></li> //align center
</ul>
```

Css:

```
ul {background-color:yellow;widht:100%; height:25px; margin:0px; padding:0px;}
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  width:200px;height:20px;
}
#l1 {background-color:red;}
#l2 {background-color:blue; margin:auto;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/edo0ujnb/1/

Tried adding `margin:auto` on `#l2`, but it doesn't work. Also tried `text-align:center` on ul, and on first `li` `float:left`, but second `li` ends up not in the center, but a bit to the right.

How can align second `li` (blue in my example) center, and first `li` (red in my example) left?

Comment: Using `margin: auto` works fine when the `li` is set to `display: block` instead of `inline-block`.

Comment: Do you want the #l2 centered in the yellow area, or in the space that remains between #l1 and the right edge of the yellow area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use positioning to move the red list item to the left, and `text-align:center` on the `<ul>` to center the blue list item:

```css
ul {
    background-color:yellow;
    width:100%;
    height:25px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
}
ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    width:200px;
    height:20px;
}
#l1 {
    background-color:red;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
}
#l2 {
    background-color:blue;
    margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li id="l1"></li>
    <li id="l2"></li>
</ul>
```